# Remove column using awk

Tags: unix, awk, split

I want to remove column,

this is my command:

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '{ $1=$2=$3"" ; $0=substr($0,37) } 1' PURCHASE_testing.csv > testing.csv
```

My input:

```
Account num|Car|Type|Name|Class|Price
xxxxxxxxxx |A  |Honda| Fara |A|rm20k
xxxxxxxxxx | B | Proton|Afiq |B|rm40k
```

I managed to remove first 3 column in row 1 but in row 2 and 3 the string not manage to remove.

My output:

```
       Name      Class      Price              
0101   Fara       A          rm2
1234   Afiq       B          rm4
```

I want output be:

```
Name Class Price
Fara   A   rm2
Afiq   B   rm4
```

Comment: You really need to give the _input_ as well.

Comment: Edited already @Gene

Comment: I don't see `|` separator within your input(according to `-F"|"`)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest having it but forget to put..i edit back for u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To print all but first 3 columns use the following approach:

For the input `PURCHASE_testing.csv` file contents:

```
Account num|Car|Type|Name|Class|Price 
0101 |A |Honda| Fara |A|rm20k 
1234 |B | Proton|Afiq |B|rm40k
```

---

```
awk -F"|" '{$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}' PURCHASE_testing.csv > testing.csv
```

Now, the `testing.csv` file contents should look like:

```
Name Class Price 
 Fara  A rm20k 
Afiq  B rm40k
```

Comment: to print all but not for first three columns :) @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @Jiji, in terms of English grammar, phrase `To print all but first 3 columns` is also correct

Comment: If my full command like this? 
**awk -v date="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F\| 'NR==1 {h=$0; next}
{file="SAMPLE_"$1"_"$2"_"date".csv";  
print (a[file]++?"": "DETAIL "date"" ORS h ORS) $0 > file} END{for(file in a) print "EOF " a[file] > file}' HIRE_PURCHASE_testing.csv** , how can I added the below command? @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @Jiji, as for your new command, to try to help you I should see the contents of `HIRE_PURCHASE_testing.csv` file and the expected output

Comment: I'm sorry. My input file is PURCHASE_testing.csv and my output should be  testing.csv. My command now are **awk -v date="$(date +"%d%m%Y")" -F\| 'NR==1 {h=$0; next} {file="testing_"$1""$2""date".csv"; print (a[file]++?"": "DETAIL "date"" ORS h ORS) $0 > file} END{for(file in a) print "EOF " a[file] > file}' PURCHASE_testing.csv** How can I add awk -F"|" '{$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}' PURCHASE_testing.csv > testing.csv inside my current command? I want to add on the command @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: I manage to do this awk -F"|" '{$1=$2=$3=""; print $0}' PURCHASE_testing.csv > testing.csv but how can I remove the blank space in first field?

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"} {print $4,$5,substr($6,1,4)}' f
Name Class Pric
Fara  A rm20
Afiq  B rm40
```

> Explanation : substr($6,1,4) fetching 1 to 4 character from column 6.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.